# Indoor GPS or autonomous control Solution

Tags: gps, indoors

Is there any budget solution to operate a drone indoors? I want to use it with Pixhawk 2.4.8.
As GPS does not work indoors, autonomous flight becomes impossible. So, is there any solution to provide a GPS signal indoors, so that the drone can get its positional data?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: my current thoughts would be that its probably easiest to use a small camera drone with SLAM for indoors operations (havent actually tried it out yet)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions are starting to appear that use [Ultra-wideband technology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-wideband) (same tech used by 'Smart Tags') for indoor/GNSS-denied locations. Some even output NMEA sentences to imitate a GNSS receiver, to easily integrate to existing autopilots.

I've not used this so can't recommend any examples (or how well/if it works), but a web search for 'UWB drone positioning' gives a number of results as a start point for further research.